# Jenkins declarative pipeline - multibranch run builds one by one

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I am struggling to get this thing working:

In my multibranch pipeline project, I applied the lock but still two branches are build in time. Any solution here??
Our idea is to build one branch in time..

```
// Build the branch
    stage('Build the branch') {
        steps {
            echo '*** BUILD PHASE ***'
            lock(resource: null, label: 'Build phase') {
                script {
                    for (String profile : profiles) {
                        echo "Build with profile: ${profile}"
                        def buildOutput = buildCountry(profile)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the plugin's exact behavior, yet, but have you tried to use `resource` instead of  `label`? That seems to be the default one.. (e.g. `lock('build')`)

Comment: No, I did not, will try.

Comment: hey, did it work?

Comment: Unfortunately not. There is no such a possibility as making it concurrent.